# GET http://localhost:4200/undefined while displaying image from firebase

Tags: angular

[image]I want to display image stored in firebase but getting error as GET http://localhost:4200/undefined 404 (Not Found)

I tried adding the condition as *ngIf="albumImages.userImage!== undefined" the error is gone but still the image is not displaying.

HTML File

```
<h1>Your Gallery</h1>
<div class="uk-grid-match uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
    <div *ngIf="albumImages.length > 1">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-body">
                    <img  [src]="getSantizeUrl(albumImages.userImage)" width="180" class="uk-margin-large-left uk-margin-medium-top" />
            </div>

        <div class="uk-flex" *ngFor="let image of albumImages">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-body" *ngFor="let singleImage of image.multiImages">
                    <img [src]="getSantizeUrl(singleImage)" width="180" class="uk-margin-large-left uk-margin-medium-top" />
            </div>

        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

TS File

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.imageUpload.getImages().subscribe((res)=> {
      this.albumImages = res;
      console.log(this.albumImages);
    },
    error => {
      this.error = error.message,
      console.log(error);

    } 
    );
  }
  public getSantizeUrl(url : string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

Single File Upload  Form Component TS File

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }
  initForm() {
    this.singleImageForm = this.fb.group({
      imageName : ['', Validators.required],
      uploadDate: [''],
      userImage: ['', Validators.required]

    });

  }
  public getSantizeUrl(url : string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}


  /* Preview Single Image Function */

  onFileUpload(event:any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.singleImageForm.patchValue({
          userImage: reader.result
        });
        this.url = event.target.files;

      };
  }
  else {
    UIkit.notification({message:'Only Single Image can be uploaded', status: 'danger'});
  }
}
  onSubmit() {
    this.imageUpload.singleImageSubmit(this.singleImageForm.value).subscribe((res) => console.log(res))
    UIkit.notification({message: 'Image Uploaded Successfully', status: 'success'});
  }

}
```

Service File

```
getImages() {
    return this.http.get<{[key: string]: IPhotos}>('https://angularimageupload-3f681.firebaseio.com/.json').pipe( map (responseData => {
      const albumArray: IPhotos[] = [];
      for(const key in responseData) {
        if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          albumArray.push({  id: key, ...responseData[key] })
        }
      }
      return albumArray;

    }))
  }
```

Image should be displayed store in firebase.

Comment: Hello ! Could you add an example of responseData in your answer please ? It's hard to know what causes your issue without it ;)

Comment: Why are you even getting images with `http`?  With that comment I do though assume you are using firebase in some form.

Comment: Album image is array. but you are try like `albumImages.userImage` is wrong

Comment: What is inside the `albumImages` array?

Comment: I have added image on my question

Comment: @Martin Choraine I have added screenshot of my responseData in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 array. In the first array there is no `userImage`. So that the `undefined` error will occur. Try the below code. i hope it will solve

```js
<h1>Your Gallery</h1>
<div class="uk-grid-match uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
    <div  *ngFor="let image of albumImages">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-body"  *ngIf="image.userImage">
                    <img  [src]="getSantizeUrl(image?.userImage)" width="180" class="uk-margin-large-left uk-margin-medium-top" />
            </div>

        <div class="uk-flex">
<div *ngIf="image?.multiImages">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-body" *ngFor="let singleImage of image.multiImages">
                    <img [src]="getSantizeUrl(singleImage)" width="180" class="uk-margin-large-left uk-margin-medium-top" />
            </div>
</div>

        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Error is gone but the image is not displaying. Earlier multiImages was displaying, now the images are not displaying.

Comment: here what is `userImage`  and what is `multiImages`

Comment: Can you try now

Comment: MutiImages containes the multiple Images and userImage contains only one Image. Now the only multiImages is displaying I want both the userImage and multiImages to be displayed from firebase

Comment: Try now, I made some changes

Comment: Yeah tried only multiImages  images are displaying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197555/discussion-between-velusamy-venkatraman-and-divya-dave).